# Change JQuery Bootgrid URL Programmatically

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-bootgrid

I'm just trying out Jquery bootgrid and several other js grid scripts for my current assignment, so bare with me if this question is awkward.
I need to know whether (and how) Jquery Bootgrid support changing the URL programmatically and refresh its rows with data from the new URL. My current script is as follows, I need to be able to change the URL at run time, depends on user's selection (source #1-#10) and refresh the contents dynamically. Thanks a million in advance for the help

```
var myrequestgrid = $("#myrequestgrid").bootgrid({
    caseSensitive: false,
    ajax: true,
    selection: true, // Enable row selection
      multiSelect: true, // Allow multiple rows to be selected
    url: "resource/myrequestdatafromsource1.php"})
```

Comment: if you are looking for a table I'd go for dataTable that supports all the features you are looking for

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In short you need to destroy existing bootgrid with `$("#grid").bootgrid("destroy")` and rebind the bootgrid inorder to change the url. Also, you need to change the dom of your table since, it uses the [data attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes) the data in row. Following example shows how you can implement the dynamic data from multiple api.

```js
$("#grid-data").find("thead").html(`<tr>
      <th data-column-id="id" data-type="numeric">ID</th>
      <th data-column-id="title">Title</th>
      <th data-column-id="price">Price</th>
    </tr>`);
bindBootGrid($("#selectOption").val(), productResponse);

function productResponse(response) {
  return {
    current: 1,
    rowCount: response.limit,
    rows: response.products,
    total: response.total
  };
}


function userResponse(response) {

  return {
    current: 1,
    rowCount: response.limit,
    rows: response.users,
    total: response.total
  };
}


$("#selectOption").off("change").on("change", function() {

  $("#grid-data").bootgrid("destroy");

  if ($(this).attr("data-handel") == "product") {
    $("#grid-data").find("thead").html(`<tr>
      <th data-column-id="id" data-type="numeric">ID</th>
      <th data-column-id="title">Title</th>
      <th data-column-id="price">Price</th>
    </tr>`);
    bindBootGrid($(this).val(), productResponse);
  } else {
    $("#grid-data").find("thead").html(`<tr>
      <th data-column-id="id" data-type="numeric">ID</th>
      <th data-column-id="firstName">First Name</th>
      <th data-column-id="lastName">Last Name</th>
    </tr>`);
    bindBootGrid($(this).val(), userResponse);
  }

});


function bindBootGrid(url, callback) {
  var grid = $("#grid-data").bootgrid({
    ajaxSettings: {
      method: "GET",
      cache: false
    },
    ajax: true,
    navigation: 0,
    url: url,
    responseHandler: function(response) {
      return callback(response);
    }
  });
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-bootgrid/1.3.1/jquery.bootgrid.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-bootgrid/1.3.1/jquery.bootgrid.min.js"></script>
<select id="selectOption">
  <option value="https://dummyjson.com/products" , data-handel="product">Products</option>
  <option value="https://dummyjson.com/users" data-handel="user">Users</option>
</select>
<table id="grid-data" class="table table-condensed table-hover table-striped">
  <thead>
  </thead>
</table>
```